# How to "minify" an array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

So suppose I create an array with 5 spaces, like so - `String[] myArray = new String[5]`. Then suppose I define some of those items, but leave some of them null (or whatever the Java term is for an undefined array item/variable), like so:

```
myArray[0] = "foo";
myArray[2] = "bar";
myArray[4] = "foobar";
```

Is there a way I can "minify" that array, squeezing out all the null items (not changing the size of it)? So that the index of "foo" stays at 0, but "bar"'s index becomes 1, and "foobar" resides at 2, with the last 2 spaces being empty? Long story short - shuffle around the items in an array, pushing all the null items to the end, while maintaining the relative order of the other items. Is there already a predefined Java method for that, or do I need to make my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the following approach (*without overhead of Collections instance*):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArraySample {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String[] src = new String[] { "foo", null, "bar", null, "foobar" };
        String[] dest = new String[src.length];

        int i = 0;
        for (String s : src) {
            if (s != null) {
                dest[i++] = s;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(src));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dest));
    }

}
```

Comment: Do I need my main method to throw those exceptions?

Comment: Oh :O so I don't need the `java.io.*` imports either I'm presuming?

Comment: @Spaeth You can do it without creating an other array.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with only the source array :

```
    String[] src = new String[] { "foo", "foo3", null,null, "bar", null,null, "foobar", "foo2", null,"foo5",null };
    int lastNullIdx = -1;

    for (int i=0; i <src.length ; i++) {
        if (src[i] == null) {
            if(lastNullIdx==-1)lastNullIdx=i;
        }
        else if(lastNullIdx!=-1){
            src[lastNullIdx++]=src[i];
            src[i]=null;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(src));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that there is a method for it. If therewould be something like that, it would be in java.util.Arrays. I would do it like this

```
String[] src = new String[] { "foo", null, "bar", null, "foobar" };

for (int c = 0, j = 0; c < src.length; c++) {
    if (src[c] != null) {
        src[j++] = src[c];
        src[c] = null;
    }
}
```

edit:

```
String[] src = new String[] { "foo", null, "bar", null, "foobar" };
Comparator<String> NEW_ORDER = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String e1, String e2) {
        if(e1 == null)return 1;
        if(e2 == null)return -1;
        return 0;
    }
Arrays.sort(src, NEW_ORDER);
```

Should work aswell, since Arrays.sort is a stable sort, but i think the other solution is better, since its O(n) and not O(n log n)

Comment: The first solution is already a beauty, no need for the second one :)

Answer (score 1):

In-place minification, simpler code:

```
public static String[] minify(String[] x) {
  int d = 0;
  for (String s : x) if (s != null) x[d++] = s;
  while (d < x.length) x[d++] = null;
  return x;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
      minify(new String[] {"foo", null, "bar", null, "foobar"})));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [functionaljava](http://functionaljava.org/),

```
array(myArray).filter(new F<String, Boolean>() {
  public Boolean f(String s) { 
    return s != null; 
  }
});
```

This will *retain* the elements that satisfy the given conditions. The result will be the new array returned by `filter`.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I misread the question before. Here's how you can squeeze out `null`s to right.

```
array(myArray).sort(
  booleanOrd.comap(new F<String, Boolean>() {
    public Boolean f(String s) {
      return s == null;
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: cool approach! the same approach could be obtained by using [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) by applying [Collections.filter](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29)

Comment: Right. However functionaljava is more complete with regards to functional programming abstractions.

Comment: but I'm just wondering on this case you will filter out the null elements right? And the intention was to present the same array size just shifting the not null elements to the left...

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question before. And thank you for hinting to that! I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Java is already prepared for such sorting problem using the Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator c) method:

```
Arrays.sort(myArray, new StringNullComparator());
```

with

```
class StringNullComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)
    {
        if(s1==null && s2!=null) return 1;
        else if(s1!=null && s2==null) return -1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

This way you can even sort the null values to lower indecees by inverting the value returned from the compare method.